# Open file using UIDocumentInteractionController - Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.ios, uidocument

I am working on Xamarin Forms application. The app currently downloads files from URL and save it in Documents directory of the phone.
What I intend to achieve now is to view those downloaded files on Button Click. The app popups the default programs available to open the file.

I've done so in android. But I am having problems in iOS.
I am using "UIDocumentInteractionController" to view the files. But the button click event doesn't display any options.

Is there any problem in this code ?

```
NSUrl URL = new NSUrl(filePath, false);
var viewer = UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl(URL);
viewer.PresentOpenInMenu(new RectangleF(0, -260, 320, 320), this.View, true);
```

Following is my complete code sample. Please help.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Foundation;
using Plugin.DownloadManager;
using Plugin.DownloadManager.Abstractions;
using UIKit;

namespace PracticeApp.iOS
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        string filePath;
        string fileName;

    public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        // SOME CODE
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        // SOME CODE FOR DOWNLOADIND THE FILE FROM URL

        // Downloaded File Path
        // /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6A3459AC-A7BC-40CE-A3F9-6581215E3421/data/Containers/Data/Application/BC5B26E9-ABD9-4310-96F0-57194837A73E/Documents/test1.pptx

        // AFTER DOWNLOAD FINISHED
        var buttonO = new UIButton(UIButtonType.RoundedRect) {
            Frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds,
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red
        };

        NSString urlString = new NSString(filePath);
        NSUrl myFileUrl = new NSUrl(urlString);
        Console.WriteLine(myFileUrl.AbsoluteString);
        string absPath = myFileUrl.Path;

        buttonO.TouchUpInside += (sender1, e1) => {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("File Path: " + filePath);

            OpenFileFunc();
        };

        Add(buttonO);
    }


    public void OpenFileFunc()
    {
        var firstController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.ChildViewControllers.First().ChildViewControllers.Last().ChildViewControllers.First();

        var navcontroller = firstController as UINavigationController;

        //var UIDocumentInteractionController = new UIDocumentInteractionController();
        //UIDocumentInteractionController.Url = filePath;
        //UIDocumentInteractionController.Delegate = new DocInteractionC(navcontroller);
        //UIDocumentInteractionController.PresentPreview(true);


        var controller = GetVisibleViewController();
        var viewer = UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename(filePath));
        viewer.PresentOpenInMenu(controller.View.Frame, controller.View, true);

    }

    //public class DocInteractionC : UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate
    //{
    //    readonly UINavigationController _navigationController;

    //    public DocInteractionC(UINavigationController controller)
    //    {
    //        _navigationController = controller;
    //    }

    //    public override UIViewController ViewControllerForPreview(UIDocumentInteractionController controller)
    //    {
    //        return _navigationController;
    //    }

    //    public override UIView ViewForPreview(UIDocumentInteractionController controller)
    //    {
    //        return _navigationController.View;
    //    }

    //}

    private UIViewController GetVisibleViewController(UIViewController controller = null)
    {
        controller = controller ?? UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;

        if (controller.PresentedViewController == null)
            return controller;

        if (controller.PresentedViewController is UINavigationController) {
            return ((UINavigationController)controller.PresentedViewController).VisibleViewController;
        }

        if (controller.PresentedViewController is UITabBarController) {
            return ((UITabBarController)controller.PresentedViewController).SelectedViewController;
        }

        return GetVisibleViewController(controller.PresentedViewController);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This code is not working:
`NSUrl URL = new NSUrl(filePath, false);`
`var viewer = UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl(URL);`
`viewer.PresentOpenInMenu(new RectangleF(0, -260, 320, 320), this.View, true);`